# Как вывести даннные из бд через RedBeanPHP?

Tags: php, redbeanphp

Это не работает   `$hash  = R::findOne( 'user', ' hash = ? ', '"'.$_COOKIE['id'].'"' );`
крч, как вывести переменную hash с помощью библиотеки RedBeanPHP из таблицы user по $_COOKIE['id']?

Comment: Почему не работает? Какие ошибки? Что в логах?

Comment: исправил... просил array